# What's the best way to query a payload array in javascript to capture specific objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to capture the **attributes.value** objects via JavaScript when specifying the name like email, fname, lname, etc. I've tried a few things but no success. Any ideas?

Sample payload:

```
{
attributes: [
{ handle: 'email', name: 'Email', value: 'john.doe@gmail.com'},
{ handle: 'fname', name: 'First Name', value: 'John' },
{ handle: 'lname', name: 'Last Name', value: 'Doe' },
{ handle: 'zip', name: 'Postal Code', value: '45383' }
],
status: [ { group: 'student', school: 'UCF' } ]
}
```

Comment: _"I've tried a few things"_ please share these

Comment: `if (bodyParsed.attributes && bodyParsed.attributes.length >0){

const email = bodyParsed.attributes.find(({ handle }) => handle === 'email');

console.log("The result is" + email);

} `    <br/> let bodyParsed;
    try {
      console.log(body);
     bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body);
    } catch (jsonError) {
      return callback(new Error(body));
    }

Comment: Sorry... new one here and not sure how to format properly. I've also tried `Group: bodyParsed.status.group`